# Android screen-size database

Tags: android, screen-size

Is there a database, which contains resolution in pixels, screen-size and density for each particular device?

Something like this:

Samsung Galaxy S2   | 480 x 800  |  screen-size=normal  |  density=hdpi

Google Nexus        | 1280x720   |  screen-size=normal  |  density=xhdpi

Comment: also processor, BogoMips, support for OpenGl ES 2.0, ... would be useful

Comment: In short there's no such list AFAIK but some lists are present not exactly full ones but at least they have some info  https://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=rdm8c2ZfSDKd5l-dVy4SrnA&output=html http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Android_devices

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Screen sizes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6231856/android-screen-sizes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.android.com/devices/ is the list I use a lot

Edit : this seems to be the new best location after previous link was turned into marketing content 
It's also more of a database now 
https://material.io/devices/

Comment: The link now redirects to a marketing page, no longer useful.

Comment: Thanks @Sampo - I updated it to a newer link . Hope it helps

Comment: Newer link not very useful either now

Answer (score 0):

You can either detect it on the device using this: [Get screen dimensions in pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/android-how-to-get-screen-dimensions)

Or you would have to create it by going to www.phonearena.com/

But I don't know if anyone is going to construct a db like this and then just hand it out.

Answer (score 0):

I like https://www.gsmarena.com, it has a comprehensive database of nearly all the devices with screen dimensions, densities and much more other information.

Answer (score -1):

Check [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) out for the different screen sizes and the category under which they fall.....for phone specific details, you can visit gsmarena.com