# Mobile App - Screen Width and Height

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, blackberry, jquery-mobile

Based on Blackberry , Andriod and iPhone ... what are the various screen resolutions available in Market ?

Comment: Do you mean screen size. That is easy it is x by y. Where x and y are positive integers. Sorry it is not as easy as you hoped, it is like asking what is the screen size of a Mac, Gnu/Linux, Microsoft computer.

Comment: Richard, you have not understood what I have asked. I am sorry. Please look the answeres given below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### BlackBerry

Here is a *pretty good* list for BlackBerry devices (read the whole thread, as it's been updated with newer devices in the more recent posts):

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/List-of-Blackberry-Devices-with-resolution/td-p/556066

A less comprehensive list of BlackBerry [icon sizes can be found here](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/24222/Dimensions_for_screens_images_and_icons_476251_11.jsp)

### iPhone

Here's a link for iPhone icon sizes:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html

iPhone screen dimensions are easy:

- iPhone 2G, 3G, 3GS - 320x480
- iPhone 4, 4S - 640x960

iPods and iPads add more devices, but you didn't specify that you were looking for those.

### Android

The Android question has been asked several times on Stack Overflow.  [You can see this answer for a good place to start](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6231886/119114) on screen sizes.

For Android icons, I like to use the [Android Asset Studio](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html).  If you use it to build icons, it can help you make sure you get all the right sizes.

Answer (score 0):

There are no fixed background dimensions for BlackBerry and Android. iPhone's can be taken as fixed, but it's always better to be future proof and go with scaling your images to fit as many sizes as you can (within reason).

Answer (score -1):

Blackberry and Android vary wildly based on the specific model.

For iPhone info, go here: http://bit.ly/KPx2Zx